# A little bit more difficult problem regarding rooted plane trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

A question regarding rooted plane trees bothers me. We know that the number of rooted plane trees with $n$ nodes equals to $n-{th}$ Catalan number, that is $|Tn| = Cn$.

But what is this number if we have the restriction that the first subtree of these trees has k nodes, where $k <= n-1$?

I will be waiting for your help to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by 'the first subtree has k nodes' is that the root's first child has k - 1 descendants, and together with them forms a subtree with k nodes, then the answer is just $$C_k * C_{n-k} $$ since there are $C_k$ possibilities for the subtree and $C_{n - k}$ for the remainder of the tree (that is, the whole tree with the first branch cut off).